# shellscript and awk extraction to calculate averages

Tags: shell, awk

I have a shell script that contains a loop. This loop is calling another script. The output of each run of the loop is appended inside a file (outOfLoop.tr). when the loop is finished, awk command should calculate the average of specific columns and append the results to another file(fin.tr). At the end, the (fin.tr) is printed.

I managed to get the first part which is appending the results from the loop into (outOfLoop.tr) file. also, my awk commands seem to work... But I'm not getting the final expected output in terms of format. I think I'm missing something. Here is my try:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm outOfLoop.tr
rm fin.tr

x=1
lmax=4

while [ $x -le $lmax ]

do
calling another script >> outOfLoop.tr
x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
cat outOfLoop.tr
#/////////////////
#//I'm getting the above part correctly and the output is :
27 194 119 59 178

27 180 100 30 187

27 175 120 59 130

27 189 125 80 145
#////////////////////
#back again to the script

echo "noRun\t A\t B\t C\t D\t E"
echo "----------------------\n"

#// print the total number of runs from the loop 
echo "$lmax\t">>fin.tr

#// extract the first column from the output which is 27
awk '{print $1}' outOfLoop.tr  >>fin.tr
echo "\t">>fin.tr


#Sum the column---calculate average
awk '{s+=$5;max+=0.5}END{print s/max}' outOfLoop.tr  >>fin.tr
echo "\t">>fin.tr


awk '{s+=$4;max+=0.5}END{print s/max}' outOfLoop.tr  >>fin.tr
echo "\t">>fin.tr

awk '{s+=$3;max+=0.5}END{print s/max}' outOfLoop.tr  >>fin.tr
echo "\t">>fin.tr


awk '{s+=$2;max+=0.5}END{print s/max}' outOfLoop.tr  >> fin.tr
echo "-------------------------------------------\n" 


cat fin.tr
rm outOfLoop.tr
```

I want the format to be like :

```
noRun    A       B           C            D         E
----------------------------------------------------------
4        27      average    average      average   average
```

I have incremented `max` inside the awk command by 0.5 as there was new line between the out put of the results (output of outOfLoop file)

Comment: Why aren't you doing the whole lot in [tag:awk]?

Comment: My problem is not from the shell script. It's from awk formatting !!If I do the whole in awk... the problem is still not solved !!

Comment: Writing the whole thing in awk would not guarantee to solve your problem but it'd make it a whole lot less likely that you'd have a problem in the first place and a whole lot easier to solve it if you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file
27 194 119 59 178

27 180 100 30 187

27 175 120 59 130

27 189 125 80 145

$ cat tst.awk
NF {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        sum[i] += $i
    }
    noRun++
}
END {
    fmt="%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s\n"
    printf fmt,"noRun","A","B","C","D","E"
    printf "----------------------------------------------------------\n"
    printf fmt,noRun,$1,sum[2]/noRun,sum[3]/noRun,sum[4]/noRun,sum[5]/noRun
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
noRun     A         B         C         D         E
----------------------------------------------------------
4         27        184.5     116       57        160
```

Comment: Thank you... the code works perfect..however, 'A' value is not printed. Not sure why ???

Comment: Interesting. Most modern awks will "remember" the values from the last record read so you can access it directly in the END section so usually you'd be able to use $1 in the END section as I did and it'd refer to the first field of the last record read. You might want to think about getting GNU awk for this and many much more useful capabilities.